# Application that have one rest controller vs performance

Tags: java, spring

that might be a little hypotetic question and hard to answer but I am not sure where it should be asked. Let say we have quite complex aplications, and for unknown reason for world we decide to create one @RestController instead of many. (I know that is anti-pattern) but I'm insteresting if it will have impact on performance?

Comment: http server is already single "rest controller"

Comment: thank you very much for answer. Should i delete question now?

Comment: Would it be one rest controller class with multiple endpoints or with just a single endpoint?